# How to return an array of folders?

Tags: community, commerce-cloud

I'm trying to return all possible folders with 'blog-content' in the ID, is there a method for this or a different way of doing this? So far I can only get one result if it is the exact match. Like so:

```
const ContentSearchModel = require('dw/content/ContentSearchModel');

const apiContentSearchModel = new ContentSearchModel();

apiContentSearchModel.setFolderID('blog-content');

apiContentSearchModel.search();

const folderSearchResult = apiContentSearchModel.getFolderID();
```

I can't see any method for returning an array of folders matching the query:

[image]

Update:

So i think this may be possible a different way - by content searching all articles with say 'article' in the id and then using the getMatchingFolders method in the contentSearchRefinements class to output the collection of folders. Although now i don't really understand how to run the returned articles through the refinement class. any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track using ContentSearchModel. If the folder called `blog-content` is a parent folder for all the other folders that have `blog-content` in their IDs then you should be able to achieve what you want using the recursive search feature. I also would assume that a Folder Refinement is configured in Business Manager on the root of the library. eg:

[image: A screenshot illustrating the location and sample configuration of a Folder Content Search Refinement in Salesforce Commerce Cloud B2C's Business Manager application]

If so, the first thing you'll want to do is ensure you're also setting the `recursiveFolderSearch` flag to `true` before calling `search()`. eg:

```
apiContentSearchModel.setRecursiveFolderSearch(true);
```

You should be able to then get a collection of the search refinements using:

```
var refinements = apiContentSearchModel.getRefinements();
```

Once you've acquired a collection of available refinements, you'll want to call:

```
var folderRefinement = refinements.getFolderRefinementDefinition();
```

Now that you have a reference to the `FolderRefinementDefinition` you can now get the refinement values associated with it. Those will be the folders where content search hits were found. You can get them using:

```
var folders = refinements.getRefinementValues(folderRefinement);
```

`folders` is now a collection of ContentSearchRefinementValue objects. Each of which would have a `getValue()` method which should be the ID of the folder. You can get the displayName of the folders using `getDisplayValue()`. You can also get the number of assets included in that folder that match the search using the `getHitCount()` method.

Keep in mind that if you have multiple levels of these folders that the `getHitCount()` method would reflect any sub-folders as well.

Comment: ha amazing thank you! just noticed you work at astound.. im trying to make changes to a system built by astound funnnily enough!

Comment: wooop made it work, legend!

Comment: just one question: how come there is a `global` value in the `folders` collection?

Comment: @alecbaldwin I'm not sure what you mean by a `global` value in the folders collection. Can you share a screenshot or more detailed description?